# Why does `py.test --last-failed` skip many tests altough no tests had failed before?

Tags: python, pytest

Out of sudden `py.test --last-failed` skips a lot of tests although *no* test failed in a previous test run. Here is the output of first running `py.test --vv` and then `py.test --vv --last-failed`:

```
$venv/bin/py.test -vv
======================================================================= test session starts =======================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-4.6.3, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0 -- /Users/lars/coding/talea/fahrtwind/products/backend/venv/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/lars/coding/talea/fahrtwind/products/backend, inifile: pytest.ini, testpaths: tests
plugins: forked-1.0.2, env-0.6.2, xdist-1.28.0, cov-2.7.1
collected 888 items
...                                                                                                                                     
<HERE ALL 888 TESTS ARE RUN AND ALL PASS>
...
=================================================================== 888 passed in 63.89 seconds ===================================================================
$
$
$venv/bin/py.test -vv --last-failed
======================================================================= test session starts =======================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-4.6.3, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0 -- /Users/lars/coding/talea/fahrtwind/products/backend/venv/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/lars/coding/talea/fahrtwind/products/backend, inifile: pytest.ini, testpaths: tests
plugins: forked-1.0.2, env-0.6.2, xdist-1.28.0, cov-2.7.1
collected 303 items                                                                                                                                               
run-last-failure: 181 known failures not in selected tests (skipped 206 files)
...
<HERE ONLY 303 TESTS ARE RUN>
...
```

Why does `py.test --last-failed` skip many tests altough no tests had failed before?

Comment: Probably  the last failures of a run that actually had failures?

Comment: Uh, if no tests failed before, then shouldn't it skip *all* the tests? Why are you surprised that it's skipping "many" tests?

Comment: What does `-vv` mean anyway there is just `-v`?

Comment: The behavior of `py.test --last-failed` is to rerun _all_ tests if non has previously failed. It's very weired that it just runs a few tests which previously hadn't failed!

Comment: @Aran-Fey It would be fine if it didn't run any test at all, but pytest runs a part of the tests which previously didn't fail. There's some odd behavior now, the tool chain had previously actually worked for me.

Comment: If the previous run suceeded, `pytest` should response with `no previously failed tests, not deselecting items` on rerunning last failures. Something's stale in the cache (maybe polluted or incorrectly handled by some plugin?) - can you rerun the tests with `pytest --cache-clear` and then test the collection with `pytest --last-failed --collect-only`?

Comment: @hoefling Deleting the cache with `--cache-clear` fixed my problem as you suggested. I had previously moved my python project into a different folder – that might have caused the broken cache. If you post your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @hoefling PS: You must be surely a master on caching problem because you built an entire website around.

Comment: Ah, you mean the http://shouldiblamecaching.com/? I'm not the author of it, but it's indeed a good reminder to myself for what can go wrong when caching is used :-) Glad I could help und liebe Grüße nach Berlin!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, invalidating the cache was the solution: either rerun the tests via

```
$ pytest --cache-clear
```

or, if the test suite takes a lot of time to rerun, simply delete the `.pytest_cache` directory in the project root (or `.cache` for older versions of `pytest`). Also, citing the [Clearing Cache content](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/cache.html#clearing-cache-content) section:

> You can instruct `pytest` to clear all cache files and values by adding the `--cache-clear` option like this:
>
> ```
> pytest --cache-clear
> ```
>
> This is recommended for invocations from Continuous Integration servers where isolation and correctness is more important than speed.

Thus, it is a good practice to instruct your CI server to invalidate the cache on each run so you have a reference when encountering unexpected failures due to local caching.